# How to set 3 radiobutton with its groupname in a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button, repeater

I need to set 3 different groups of radio button in a repeater. Using groupname property for it wasn't enough. So, after researching, I use a bit of JS and it works. My problem is when I want to implement more than one group of radiobuttons. Can anyone help me?

My best approach is:

**CSHTML**

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeaterImages" OnItemDataBound="repeaterImages_ItemDataBound">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <span>
          <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rbLogoSeleccionado" Text='Logo 0' GroupName="nombreLogo" /><br />
          <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rbLogoSeleccionadoApp" Text='Logo 1' GroupName="nombreLogoApp" /><br />
          <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rbLogoSeleccionadoAppBlanco" Text='Logo 2' GroupName="nombreLogoAppBlanco" />
   </span>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    function SetUniqueRadioButton(nameregex, current) {

        for (i = 0; i < document.forms[0].elements.length; i++) {

            elm = document.forms[0].elements[i]

            if (elm.type == 'radio') {

                elm.checked = false;
            }
        }
        current.checked = true;
    }
</script>
```

**CS**

```
protected void repeaterImages_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            RadioButton rbLogoSeleccionado = (RadioButton)e.Item.FindControl("rbLogoSeleccionado");
            RadioButton rbLogoSeleccionadoApp = (RadioButton)e.Item.FindControl("rbLogoSeleccionadoApp");
            RadioButton rbLogoSeleccionadoAppBlanco = (RadioButton)e.Item.FindControl("rbLogoSeleccionadoAppBlanco");

            string script = "SetUniqueRadioButton('repeaterImages.*nombreLogo',this)";
            string scriptApp = "SetUniqueRadioButton('repeaterImages.*nombreLogoApp',this)";
            string scriptAppBlanco = "SetUniqueRadioButton('repeaterImages.*nombreLogoAppBlanco',this)";

            rbLogoSeleccionado.Attributes.Add("onclick", script);
            rbLogoSeleccionadoApp.Attributes.Add("onclick", scriptApp);
            rbLogoSeleccionadoAppBlanco.Attributes.Add("onclick", scriptAppBlanco);
        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        PIPEvo.Log.Log.RegistrarError(ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

With this code just getting 3 rows of radiobutton, sharing groupname behavior for all of them... (I want groupname behavior per row...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Piece of cake. Prove how newie I am in JS. I am posting the solution because is a recurrent issue in asp programming and this bug is known. Beside I cant find the solution for some radio button.

**JS**.

```
<script>
    function SetUniqueRadioButton(text, current) {
        for (i = 0; i < document.forms[0].elements.length; i++) {

            elm = document.forms[0].elements[i]

            if ((elm.type == 'radio') && (elm.value == text)) {
                elm.checked = false;
            }
        }
        current.checked = true;
    }
</script>
```

**CS**

```
     protected void repeaterImages_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
                {
                    RadioButton rbLogoSeleccionado = (RadioButton)e.Item.FindControl("rbLogoSeleccionado");
                    RadioButton rbLogoSeleccionadoApp = (RadioButton)e.Item.FindControl("rbLogoSeleccionadoApp");
                    RadioButton rbLogoSeleccionadoAppBlanco = (RadioButton)e.Item.FindControl("rbLogoSeleccionadoAppBlanco");

                    string script = "SetUniqueRadioButton('rbLogoSeleccionado',this)";
                    string scriptApp = "SetUniqueRadioButton('rbLogoSeleccionadoApp',this)";
                    string scriptAppBlanco = "SetUniqueRadioButton('rbLogoSeleccionadoAppBlanco',this)";

                    rbLogoSeleccionado.Attributes.Add("onclick", script);
                    rbLogoSeleccionadoApp.Attributes.Add("onclick", scriptApp);
                    rbLogoSeleccionadoAppBlanco.Attributes.Add("onclick", scriptAppBlanco);
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                PIPEvo.Log.Log.RegistrarError(ex);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

**CSHTML**

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeaterImages" OnItemDataBound="repeaterImages_ItemDataBound">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <span>
          <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rbLogoSeleccionado" Text='Logo 0' GroupName="nombreLogo" /><br />
          <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rbLogoSeleccionadoApp" Text='Logo 1' GroupName="nombreLogoApp" /><br />
          <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rbLogoSeleccionadoAppBlanco" Text='Logo 2' GroupName="nombreLogoAppBlanco" />
   </span>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```